# Norm on sum of function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the convention for the norm endowed on a sum of spaces $X+Y$, as well as on the intersection of spaces $X\cap Y$?

I am reading a paper where the authors use a sum of function spaces without writing the norm explicitly, and they make no further comment.

I'm thinking that maybe the most plausible norm for $X\cap Y$ is $\|f\|_X +\|f\|_Y$ with the norm for $X+Y$ then being $\min\{\|f\|_X,\|f\|_Y\}$.

Apologies if this question is a duplicate, in which case I'll be happy to delete it. I couldn't find a similar question on math stackexchange.

Comment: For general spaces $X$ and $Y$ the expressions $X \cap Y$ and $X+Y$ do not make sense. If they are subspaces of so normed vector space $Z$ then it is natural to use the norm of $Z$ on both $X+Y$ and $X \cap Y$.

Comment: Can we have a reference to the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ embed continuously into a Hausdorff topological vector space $Z$ (so that $X\cap Y$ and $X + Y$ make sense).  The norms usually used are:
$$ {\|x\|}_{X+Y} = \inf\{{\|x_1\|}_X + {\|x_2\|}_Y : x_1 + x_2 = x \} ,$$
$$ {\|x\|}_{X\cap Y} = \max\{{\|x\|}_X,{\|x\|}_Y\} .$$
The norm for $X \cap Y$ makes sense, and is equivalent to the norm you suggested.  For $X+Y$, the minimum of the two norms is, unfortunately, not  a norm.

Instead, think of the space $X \oplus Y$ with the norm $\|(x,y)\| = {\|x\|}_X + {\|y\|}_Y$.  Look at the subspace $U = \{(x,x): x \in X\cap Y\}$.  Then $X + Y$ is isomorphic to the quotient space $(X \oplus Y) / U$.  This provides a quick proof that $X + Y$ equipped with the above norm is indeed a Banach space.

Comment: ...and the main reason for this is that the intersection and the sum thus become Banach spaces if so are $X$ and $Y$.